# Accessing current ng-repeat iteration element in another scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, local, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a series of anchor tags on ng-repeat which are routed via the `fixture.id` variable to a specific details page.

I want to access the `fixture` object - from the ng-repeat scope - in the controller for the details page, but can't seem to do it.

### HTML

Page 1:

```
<a href="#/knockout/{{fixture.id}}" ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | filter: { formatted_date: '10.06.2016' }:true | limitTo: 1" class="match">

         <div class="flag-wrapper">
             <div class="flag-{{fixture.localteam_id}}"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="flag-wrapper">
             <div class="flag-{{fixture.visitorteam_id}}"></div>
         </div>

</a>
```

Page 2:

```
<div class="lineup_home">
  <h2>
    <span class="flag-icon-**fixture.localteam_id**}}></span>
  </h2>
  <h2>France</h2>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

So I can access fixture.id from the URL, that's fine... I want to access other properties from the fixture object, such as fixture.localteam_id. How would I do this?

Also, I know I could just access it from the getFixtures array, but that is a service that makes an $http request. I don't want to have to do this every time so it would be better to use the data that has already been populated. If that makes sense.

Comment: are you using ui.router?

Comment: No, not using ui.router, just ngRoute.

Answer (score 0):

***After Edit:***

To access other properties from the object you have retrieved through an $http request, you could create a Factory inside the "Fixture" Module.

Therefore, whenever you call the, "getFixtures" method, you update your factory, and the data can be shared by all required controllers, by injection:

```
angular.module('Fixture')
.factory('FixtureFactory', function() {
   //Get & set methods.
})

.controller('FixtureTableController', ['$scope', 'FixtureFactory',
    function($scope, FixtureFactory) {
   //Call getFixtures
   //Call SET method from Factory.
}])

.controller('FixtureDetailsController', ['$scope', 'FixtureFactory',
    function($scope, FixtureFactory) {
   //Call GET method from Factory to retrieve fixtures array.
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear at all, my bad! Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to your second page the controller from the first page is no longer in scope and its data is no longer available. There are a lot of ways to approach this.

1. Since you're already using a service, you could store the data at the service level after it's requested and modify your service to check to see if the data is already present before performing an http request.
2. I'm not familiar with your layout, but if there's a way to display the data in a fashion that makes the detail display a child of the list, you could access it through parentscope.
3. You could inject $cacheFactory into the first controller, and use $cacheFactory.put to store the data and inject $cacheFactory into the second controller and use $cacheFactory.get to retrieve the data again.

Those are just 3 off the top of my head. You could also use local storage, cookies, etc.

Also, it sounds like you need a minimum amount of data when you render your list and more data when you display the full details of an item. It would probably be more efficient to just retrieve a list that consists of the minimal data requirements in the first state and then when you navigate to the detail state, retrieve all of the data for that item.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat creates a new scope for each element and ng-include also creates a new scope.
Scope created by ng-repeat for current element. This scope holds the current element in the iteration.